# Learning Jquery, problems with if/else statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

This is my code, that is not running. Where did I mess up?

```
$("#source").change(function() {
    var sourcestr =$("#source").val();
    if ($("#url").val().indexof('&') > -1) {
        $(".sourceHTML").text('?utm_source=' + sourcestr + '&utm_medium=eml');
    }
    else {
        $(".sourceHTML").text('&utm_source=' + sourcestr + '&utm_medium=eml');
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery reference? Try using Document ready. Which lines do not execute? Please explain in detail.

Comment: can you share the html or a jsfiddle? this js code doesn't give much info about your issue

Comment: $("#url").val().indexOf('&')  Uppercase 'O'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be safer to check in the condition if there is any parameter, instead of checking if there is more than one, like this:

```
if ($("#url").val().indexOf('?') > -1) { ... }
```